# Oracle Apex Hide Edit button in IG

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to hide the edit button which is part of the toolbar in IG.

But i cannot simply disable the actions menu as i need other options.
Is there any other way or JS code to exclusively hide only the edit button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option. For an interactive grid with static id `my_ir` put the following in "Execute when page loads"

```
var actions = apex.region( 'my_ir' ).call( "getActions" );
    actions.hide( "edit" );
```

Comment: This works but strangely when page refreshes the button is visible for fraction of a second and then hides. Maybe that has got to do with page settings?

Comment: Yeah that is expected because the javascript fires after page load only